Spring Boot: Hibernate setup failing for PostgreSQL db
I'm trying to build an API on Spring Boot version 3.1.1, but I got these errors:
2024-06-26T16:14:16.463+02:00  WARN 29090 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.example.springboot.SpringbootApplication.main(SpringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2024-06-26T16:14:16.477+02:00  WARN 29090 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-06-26T16:14:17.047+02:00  INFO 29090 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-06-26T16:14:17.063+02:00  INFO 29090 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-06-26T16:14:18.089+02:00  WARN 29090 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
2024-06-26T16:14:18.089+02:00 ERROR 29090 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-06-26T16:14:18.097+02:00 ERROR 29090 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"] [n/a]
2024-06-26T16:14:18.099+02:00  WARN 29090 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"] [n/a]
2024-06-26T16:14:18.101+02:00  INFO 29090 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-06-26T16:14:18.116+02:00  INFO 29090 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-26T16:14:18.141+02:00 ERROR 29090 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.example.springboot.SpringbootApplication.main(SpringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:698) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1

This is my application.properties:
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db-name
spring.datasource.username=postgres-user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Besides that, I set up some beans:
The model for the table:
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_FRUITS")
public class FruitsModel implements Serializable [...]

The repository:
@Repository
public interface FruitsRepositories extends JpaRepository<FruitsModel, UUID> {
}

Then in the controller:
@RestController
public class FruitController {
    @Autowired
    FruitsRepositories fruitsRepositories; [...]

I'm using postgresql on Linux Mint and my version is “(PostgreSQL) 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).”
I tried to specify the dialect with:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
However, it had no effect on the error.

Please add the full stacktrace not a snippet. You have added properties but judging from the error those aren't used, generally coming from configuring beans yourself (if you did please add them to your question as well).

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

@M.Deinum thank you for reading my question. I added the full stacktrace and the beans that you mentioned. If it is not enough information yet, please let me know, I'm new in this java world.

@sidgate thank you for reading my question. I did not understand your comment, sorry.

Have you read the error? Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" either your user or password is wrong or password authentication has been disabled for this user.

su - postgres is switching a user on the command line. Here postgres is a system user not a postgres user. So how do you access the database after switching users? Why do you need to switch to a different user anyway?

@M.Deinum Yes, you are right, I just google how to give an user and password for a db and my application is working now. I had no idea about this configuration.

@JéssicaZucco Please check my answer and let me know if it solved the problem.

"FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres" problem in the error message may be caused by that there are 2 PostgreSQL instances using the same port (e.g. PostgreSQL installation on Windows and Docker).
The issue was that the PostgreSQL Docker container was using the default port 5432 on localhost and the PostgreSQL server on Windows was using the same port on localhost. However, there were no errors when starting either of them.
Workarounds:
Option 1: Stop the `PostgreSQL` service on `Windows`

Option 2 (using `WSL`): Completely uninstall `PostgreSQL` from `Windows` and install `postgresql-client` on `WSL` (`sudo apt install 
postgresql-client-common postgresql-client libpq-dev`)

Option 3: Change the port of the `Docker` container

Here is also another example regarding to spring.datasource in application.properties:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db-name
spring.datasource.username=postgres-user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
... 

